# Find a plane perpendicular to another plane, parallel to line and from a distance to a given point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Given: Space $\rm R^{3}$, plane $\alpha$ as a cartesian equation, line $e$ as parameter equation, point P (x, y, z). Find a plane perpendicular to $\alpha$, parallel to the line $e$, and at a distance of $\sqrt{32}$ from P.

Let's name the plane that we are searching as $\beta$ ($Ax+By+Cz+D=0$, in total 4 parameters have to be found) if $\beta\perp\alpha$ than the normal vectors of these planes are $\perp$ too. From the dot product, we can get an equation for A, B, and C.

The normal vector of $\beta$ is $\perp$ to line $e$, so given that the direction of the line is known, we can get another equation for A, B, and C.

But last part is out of my understanding: from the formula of distance from the point to the plane we can get the quite complicated equation:

$\sqrt{32} = \frac{|Ax+By+Cz+D|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}}$.

I get stuck here, could someone help me?

**Solution:** (thanks guys for a hint!)  Use normal vector for the plane $\alpha$ and direction of the line $e$ to construct a cross product, which will give the normal of the plane $\beta$ (three out of 4 parameters will be known then, namely A, B, and C). Use these to solve the last equation, where the D can be obtained.

Comment: Square both sides of the distance equation. Also, you can compute suitable values for $A$, $B$ and $C$ directly: can you think of some operation that produces a vector that is perpendicular to each of two given vectors?

Comment: I just want to say if you have one of $A,B,C$ nonzero (which is the case for a plane eq.) then you can divide all the equations by that and have only three variables, one being $D/A$ (assuming you divided by $A$). The first two equations only had $B/A$ and $C/A$, so you can solve them to get both. Substitute into the final equation and do what amd told you

Comment: @acarturk Unfortunately, you don’t know ahead of time which of the three coefficients is nonzero. In practice, you can usually ignore this complication and proceed as if it’s OK to divide by the one you chose.